# My flutter app stucks at installation in debug mode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Launching lib\main.dart on SM G960U in debug mode...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(19478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19478): Process: com.gitplus.hms_mobile, PID: 19478
E/AndroidRuntime(19478): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.hms_mobile.HMS: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.hms_mobile.HMS" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gitplus.hms_mobile-Ew2-ihJM0ktPeO7wkzjY_w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gitplus.hms_mobile-Ew2-ihJM0ktPeO7wkzjY_w==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.gitplus.hms_mobile-Ew2-ihJM0ktPeO7wkzjY_w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1298)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication(ActivityThread.java:7152)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7134)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:274)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2102)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.hms_mobile.HMS" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gitplus.hms_mobile-Ew2-ihJM0ktPeO7wkzjY_w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gitplus.hms_mobile-Ew2-ihJM0ktPeO7wkzjY_w==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.gitplus.hms_mobile-Ew2-ihJM0ktPeO7wkzjY_w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1156)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1290)
E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    ... 10 more

Answer (score 0):

I think your device **SM G960U** is 32-bit. So try to add `abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'` code to your build.gradle.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId 
        minSdkVersion 
        targetSdkVersion 
        versionCode 
        versionName 

        // TODO: for 32-bit devices.
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
           // abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','x86','armeabi'
        }
    }
```